# Two listings on Google Maps/Business with a single website

Tags: seo, local-seo, google-maps, google-local-search, google-my-business

A single person runs a business with two very distinct offerings. They would like to present these under the same domain name, but they've already created two different Google business listings. The reason is that they want people to clearly show the two distinct offerings separately from one another on Google Maps.

Is it okay to then have the same domain for both? There could possibly be two different landing pages, one for each offering/service. Another possibility would be to use a second domain, but forward this to a page on the website (with the first domain).

Would be great if I could get some better insight as to whether there are any disadvantages or penalties involved with this approach – or even what exactly the best approach would be in this instance. Thank you for any answers.

Comment: Do they have more than one physical location and address?   Restaurant chains typically have a business listing for each location even when they have a single website for the restaurant chain.

Comment: No, it's just a single location

Answer (score 1):

**NAP**

It is the primary identifier of your business on the Internet.

**N**ame
**A**ddress
**P**hone

you can use a phone number instead of a website name to verify your business

https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038177/#address